# Modify Excel with Apache POI using JavaFX - WARNING occures

Tags: java, excel, javafx, apache-poi

I'm trying to edit an existing excel sheet wiht Apache POI after clicking a button via javaFX.

Now it gaves me the Error:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1 (file:/C:/Users/hendr/Documents/Java%20Programmieren/Eclipse%20Workspace/Darlehen/lib/poi-ooxml-3.17.jar) to field java.io.FilterInputStream.in
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
```

It doesn't give another Error... I'm clueless what to do.

I added all Jars to the Buildpath aswell.

My Code Controller looks like this:

package application;

```
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
@FXML
    private TextField name;

public Controller() {

    }

@FXML
    private void showExcel(ActionEvent e) throws Exception {



        String eingabeName = name.getText();
        try {

            FileInputStream vorlage = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\test.xlsx"));
            XSSFWorkbook my_xlsx_workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(vorlage);
            XSSFSheet my_worksheet = my_xlsx_workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Cell cell = null;
            cell = my_worksheet.getRow(4).getCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(eingabeName);

            vorlage.close();

            FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\test.xlsx"));
            my_xlsx_workbook.write(output_file);
            output_file.close();
            my_xlsx_workbook.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked the [FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N102B0)? What happens when you add the `--add-opens=...` arguments?

Comment: the warning means that some poi code uses deep reflection to access internal api in java9 - see http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261, the paragraph on "relaxed strong encapsulation"